# Update of Smart Group cache

Tags: smartgroups

I am on CiviCRM 4.6.2 on WordPress and recently noticed that Smart Groups are not updated.

If I look at contacts in a Smart Group it will say one number. But if I then click on *Edit Smart Group Search Criteria for ...* then the real member count is shown and the list shows the correct members. As seen on the two screenshots the membercount is different. 696 is the correct count.

[image]
[image]

Updating the cache does not resolve the issue. How do I get these groups to update?

Answer (score 5):

It turned out to be a user mistake. The members were included wrongly in the smart groups because of a parent / child issue.

> XXX is included in these Parent group(s) based on belonging to
>   group(s) which are their children.

Answer (score 3):

I am *fairly* sure I've seen this happen (on 4.5.8, at least) when contacts have been manually added to the Smart Group. So the initial page shows everyone - 'smart' and manual, but when you click 'Edit Smart Group Search Criteria for' it just shows the 'smart' contacts ie. the results of the search.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to switch the scheduled job on?![image]

Comment: It is on and is running with success.

Comment: but still not updating the smart group membership?

Comment: Added an answer - turned out to be parent / child configuration.

Comment: Glad you sorted it :-)

Comment: @huulbaek Same issue, where the smart group shows different, yet when clicking edit smart group criteria, the number of members is more (correct). Seemingly the first smart group isn't including the membership filtering criteria, yet when I click to edit the smart group, it shows. What did you mean by "XXX is included in these Parent group(s) based on belonging to group(s) which are their children." I have checked the actual group, and there isn't a parent group selected.